# checkbox value 0 or 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In many cases, I have checkboxes as below

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="custom7" value="1" id="custom7"
 checked="checked"> <label for="custom7">Email me more info?</label>
```

Now when the checkbox is checked the value should be 1 as in value=1 . If the checkbox is unchecked, I want the value to be zero as in value=0. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you not evaluate on the server side, such that if `value` is null or `value != 1` it must be zero?

Comment: @PaulProgrammer In addition to that, I think you can omit the `value` parameter, and the checkbox's value will only be submitted if it's checked; so you could look for existence on the server and base logic off of that

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thanks worked as in

```
$('#custom7').on('change', function(){
   this.value = this.checked ? 1 : 0;
   // alert(this.value);
}).change();
```

link:  http://jsfiddle.net/WhQaR/

Answer (score 19):

Just to be a butt and offer a slightly shorter answer:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    this.value = (Number(this.checked));
});
```

Comment: If you want shorter, use `this.value = +this.checked;`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Hey! phatskat said "shorter". I'm just trying to help that desire :)

Comment: @Ian than I think you missed my answer :D

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Ahh I see what you mean. You're right about that. I was really just referring to the use of `Number()`, which can be reduced to `+`. Your answer wins in terms of absolute shortness, but it also requires the HTML to be set up properly - `value="1"` and `checked="checked"` or the negated versions (which the OP didn't mention, except for properly setting it up in their own code). Since it actually depends on the `checked` state, it should use it (instead of toggling the `.value`).

Comment: @Ian actually I would never go with number just for shortness as you said I'd use `+` to convert boolean to Number, but I'd also go for the `bitwise XOR` operator :)

Comment: Got +10 for this answer today and came back to a lively discussion I missed. `+` is indeed quite a bit shorter, and the `^=` bitwise XOR is bananas.

Answer (score 7):

Don't forget about the `bitwise XOR` operator:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(){
    this.value ^= 1;
});
```

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(){
    this.value ^= 1;
    console.log( this.value )
});
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" name="accept" value="1" checked> I accept </label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="accept" value="0"> Unchecked example</label>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Very simple way

```
<input type="hidden" name="is_active" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="is_active" value="1" />
```

Change global checkbox behavior way

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
for (let checkbox of document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')) {
    checkbox.value = checkbox.checked ? 1 : 0;
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', e => {
            e.target.value = e.target.checked ? 1 : 0;
       });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

It makes no much sense because unchecked checkboxes are not sent to the server as said in the comments, but if you need a value in the server you can use a hidden field:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="custom7" checked="checked" /> 
<input type="hidden" value="1" id="hdncustom7" name="custom7" />
<label for="custom7">Email me more info?</label>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#custom7').on('change', function(){
   $('#hdncustom7').val(this.checked ? 1 : 0);
});
```

Using this methods you will receive `custom7` with 0 or 1 in the server

Answer (score 0):

Souldn't you try google first? Try this.

```
$('#custom7').change(function(){
     $(this).val($(this).attr('checked') ? '1' : '0');
});
```

Comment: I tried googling and found this question.  Sometimes that is the whole point of StackOverflow.  PS....I like some of the other answers better than yours

Comment: @GeorgeJempty that's great that you found a good answer that helps you!

Comment: @GeorgeJempty exactly. well said