# PHP multi update mysql bug about input[type=checkbox]

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I used JS set the checkbox value to '1' or '0' : [this js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295811/checkbox-value-0-or-1)

multi update mysql. this is a page can multi update all a website menu table

is multi update. these code can update every columns. but `blank` cannt update.

Why?

sometime if show 5 records.

**I set 3,4,5 record to `blank` = 1**;

**maybe 1,2,3 will be change to   `blank`  = 1.**

so confused about that

and I confirmed html is set to `name="blank[]"`

or what's I missed?

```
if (isset($_POST["edit_menu"])) {
    $gid =$_POST["gid"];
    $sql = "";
    $menuCount = count($_POST["id"]);

    for($i=0;$i<$menuCount;$i++) {
        $title = $_POST["title"];
        $url = $_POST["url"];
        $id = $_POST["id"];
        $blank = $_POST["blank"];

        $sql .= "UPDATE `menu` set 
                        title='" . $title[$i] . "',
                        url='" . $url[$i] . "',
                        blank='" . $blank[$i] . "'
                    WHERE id='" . $id[$i] . "' AND gid = '$gid';";

    }

    $stmt = $pdo->exec($sql);

}
```

### This is a detailed test results (3 records)

If three records are set `blank` = 1

This is successful

---

If three records are set `blank` = 0

This is successful

---

If only id: 1 set a record `blank` = 1

This is successful

---

If id: 2 Record Set `blank` = 1

The results will be id: 1 to `blank` = 1

id: 2 update failed

---

If id: 3 Record Set `blank` = 1

The results will be id: 1 to `blank` = 1

id: 3 update failed

Comment: The checkbox works differently than a select or input field. The variable isn't set when the checkbox isn't checked (not 0) and if the checkbox is checked, the value equals `On`, not 1. You have to convert it according to this behaviour.

Comment: I used JS set the checkbox value to '1' or '0' . $_POST got 1 or 0. in print_r($_POST). I see 1 and 0, not `On`

Comment: just add $blank = (isset($_POST["blank"]))?$_POST["blank"]:0;

Comment: Alberto, added.  But, if I checked 1 (no.2 or no.3) still just update the no.1 record